# Python: Can you display a single int based off the index of an int a user inputed

Tags: python-3.x, integer, user-input

So:

```
print('Enter a 4 digit number: ')
user = int(input())
```

Let's say the user inputs 4325

Is it possible to grab a single digit (say the 2) and display it back to the user without using a list? Or is a list or array required for such a thing?

Comment: `4325 // 100 % 10 == 3`

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with using a list/tuple though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, you can get a character in a string the way you would get an index from a list. In other words, you can do the following:

```py
user = input('Enter a 4 digit number: ')
num = int(user[2])
```

What does this mean? It means that you will be getting the input of the user, storing it in the variable `user`. Note that this is a string. Then you're getting the character at index 2 (the third character, not the second), and changing it to an int, and storing it in the variable `num`. Now, you can do `print(num)`, which should display the integer `2`.

Also, in Python, you can loop through strings. To achieve your other goal, you can do the following:

```py
dict = {
    "0": "a",
    "1": "b",
    "2": "c",
    "3": "d",
    "4": "e",
    "5": "f",
    "6": "g",
    "7": "h",
    "8": "i",
    "9": "j"
}

user = input('Enter a number: ')
newstr = ''
for char in user:
    newstr += dict[char]
print(newstr)
```

Let's say the user inputs `4325` again. The program will loop through the string, and store individual characters inside the string `char`. Then, it gets the value from dictionary `dict`, and adds it to `newstr`. Then, it will continue this process until it has reached the end of the string, where it will print out `newstr`, which this time holds the value `edcf`.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can input a string as a user and then split the 2nd index of it and convert integer type.

user = int(input('Enter a 4 digit number: ')[2])